# Circle animation with css and jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have to design an animation. There are two half circles top and bottom. When we hover the section the circle will animate.

Please see the image:

[image]

jsfiddle link :- https://jsfiddle.net/bharat_negi/bbdbbdn3/

HTML code:-

```
<div class="col-md-12 contant-area homeClass">
  <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
    <div class="homeinfo">
  <h2>INNOVATION</h2>
  <div class="infoIco">
    <div class="topCover"></div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
    <div class="circle circle1">
      <i><img src="images/whyinn-icon.png" alt=""></i>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
    <div class="footCover"></div>
    <div class="fullCircle"></div>
  </div>
  <p>We know digital innovation is the key to future growth.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Good for you, do you have an actual question?

Comment: Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Sometimes CSS is not the best tool for the Job.  SVG's are now very widely supported by browsers and can easily be animated.  You can even use design package to make the SVG first and then look at the SVG source to place CSS selectors etc, and then animate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this example I have created:

https://jsfiddle.net/bbdbbdn3/1/

It wont be the answer to your question, but will hopefully help you with finding a solution.

The way the "animation" in this example works is by having a vertically centered element (in this case `.curtain`) that fills the parent element and has a background color matching the parent's background. Then on hover the `.curtains` height is animated to `0`